# Как лучше реализовать систему загрузки изображений в Android Studio

Tags: android, изображения

Суть заключается в следующем. Есть список пользователей, куда должны загрузиться их изображения профиля из firebase storage.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загружать все изображения нерационально, т.к. проблемы с памятью неизбежны при большом количестве пользователей.

**Вопрос: как поступить в этой ситуации и реализовать эту функцию наиболее рационально?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите готовый лоадер картинок вроде Picasso и научите его получать картинки из Firebase.

Здесь можно подчерпнуть идеи: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896511/load-image-from-firebase-storage-with-picasso-to-imageview-in-infowindow-picass